# Exception using sprite with pyganim

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame, sprite

Good day. I'm trying to write a platformer. Basic actions like creating a map, creating a character, interaction and camera movement are already implemented. There are 4 files:

Game.py:

Responsible for creating the window, and drawing the rest. Also for enabling and disabling flags when performing any actions.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import Camera as cam
import Player as plr
import Platform as plfm


WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30


def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("JohnTeeworlds")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = plr.Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = plfm.Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = plfm.ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32
    camera = cam.Camera(cam.complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                raise SystemExit
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_w:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_s:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_a:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_d:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_w:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_s:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_d:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_a:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        camera.update(player)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Platform.py:

Just a class of platforms that describes how they look.

```
from pygame import *


class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))
```

Player.py:

Class player. Here we are already processing motion, gravity, well, here I am trying to ask the sprite to my character, at the moment on "waiting". Here an error occurs, I will describe it below.

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame import Surface, Rect
import pygame.image
import Platform as plfm
import pyganim


ANIMATION_DELAY = 0.1
ANIMATION_STAY = [('images/player/player_stay/1.png', ANIMATION_DELAY)]


class Entity(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((30,93))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 30, 93)
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        self.bolt_anim_stay = pyganim.PygAnimation(ANIMATION_STAY)
        self.bolt_anim_stay.play()

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
            if not up:
                self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
                self.bolt_anim_stay.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, plfm.ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
```

And Camera.py:

The class of the camera, which monitors the movement of the player on the level.

```
from pygame import *
import Game as game


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+game.HALF_WIDTH, -t+game.HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+game.HALF_WIDTH, -t+game.HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-game.WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-game.WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)
```

The problem is that I am trying to create an object with a picture. This is ANIMATION_STAY.
Then I do so that if the character does not go anywhere, and does not jump, then I try to draw this object.

```
    if not(left or right):
        self.xvel = 0
        if not up:
            self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.bolt_anim_stay.blit(self.image, (0, 0))
```

Also in the constructor, I'm trying to play this animation.

```
    self.bolt_anim_stay = pyganim.PygAnimation(ANIMATION_STAY)
    self.bolt_anim_stay.play()
```

When you start the program gives this exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/teeworlds/Game.py", line 125, in 
    main()

File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/teeworlds/Game.py", line 31, in main
    player = plr.Player(32, 32)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\teeworlds\Player.py", line 28, in **init**
    self.bolt_anim_stay = pyganim.PygAnimation(ANIMATION_STAY)

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\teeworlds\venv\lib\site-packages\pyganim__init__.py", line 168, in **init**

```
assert frame[1] > 0, 'Frame %s duration must be greater than zero.' % (i)
```

AssertionError: Frame 0 duration must be greater than zero.

I don't understand what and where is the error, and what caused it in general. I would be grateful for the help.

Sprites themselves, if needed:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: in self.image.fill aren't you supposed to supply a color?  isn't that a  required arg?

Comment: @Thunderwood Like this Color("#DDDDDD")?  I watched the video guide, there the person indicated the color like this (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Youre right, its for RGB, my bad

Comment: Try setting animation delay to 1 and tell me if you get the same error

Comment: Sorry for deleting having to delete my previous answer, the source for `Pyganimation` has a couple of vars that are very similar in name and I got them confused, which threw off my answer by an ENORMOUS amount lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source for the [Pyganimation Class](https://inventwithpython.com/pyganim/pyganim.py) frames are defined as each element of a list of tuples.  In your program this list is called `ANIMATION_STAY`.

In `ANIMATION_STAY` you set the value of your delay to be `0.1`, this is your mistake.  ANIMATION_DELAY is supposed to be an integer, not a float or double, so use a whole number instead of your `0.1`.

Later in the source when it does this:
`assert frame[1] > 0, 'Frame %s duration must be greater than zero.' % (i)`, it throws an error.  Your delay needs to be `>0`, but it is getting rounded down to `0`.

Comment: If set ANIMATION_DELAY on 1, then the animation plays very quickly
And, right there figured it out. Thank you so much с:

Comment: a common time to use is 100. i believe this corresponds with .1s